# As soon as possible vs. Right after

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-request

> Case sensitivity depends on a value of the `FooBarBaz` variable. The default value is `Off` and it's strongly discouraged to change it. If you really need to do so, change it back as soon as possible.
>
> ```
> FooBarBaz = On
> // Do something
> FooBarBaz = Off
> ```

*As soon as possible* sounds too harsh to me, and hence I would to replace it with something more neutral.

> If you really need to do so, change it back right after.

This phrase is emotionally correct, but I'm not sure whether it's grammatically correct. I have a feeling (I'm not sure, though) that we should specify "right after **what**". Something like this, probably:

> If you really need to do so, change it back right after **you have finished your tasks.**

But there are two problems here. First, I simply don't know how to say it really correct. *After you have finished your tasks* is nothing more than a draft.

Second, it sounds unnecessary wordy.

Comment: "As soon as possible" sounds perfect to me - not too harsh at all.

Comment: @TypeIA It has quite harsh meaning in my native language. :) I was also "scared" by the following article on Grammarly: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/as-soon-as-possible/

Comment: You are right. "Change it back right after" is not an English sentence, and "... right after you have finished your tasks" is unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: In the Grammarly blog, they are complaining about using "As soon as possible" to mean "stop anything else you are doing and obey my order immediately." That is *not* what your sentence "If you really need to do so, change it back as soon as possible" means.

Comment: I used to work in a team where we had a standard response for any request to do something "as soon as possible". We scheduled it to be done in 12 months' time. People soon learned to think about when they *really* needed us to do some work for them!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The phrase *as soon as possible* is so common that I do not think people would see it as harsh. They do not think of it as meaning immediately but more as soon as you have time. It is so common that people usually write ASAP in an informal context.

Right after would, I suspect, be fine in US English but it sounds ugly to me.

After you have finished your tasks could mean a time point in the distant future if that is how long the tasks are going to take.

Comment: 'As soon as possible' allows the recipient of the instruction some discretion; 'right after' does not, and is therefore harsher.

Answer (score 2):

To express "right after" in a more formal way, I would use the word *immediately*. As in "If you change this setting, change it back *immediately* afterwards".

I don't think "as soon as possible" is especially harsh; I think *immediately* is actually harsher. But I would call either of them totally appropriate in this case. They are not too harsh for the context you're using them in.

As far as expressing "after what", I think it will be easier to do that in a more concrete / specific way. For example:

"The FooBarBaz setting is deprecated and should no longer be used. If you need to enable the FooBarBaz setting temporarily while frobbing a gronk, please change it back *immediately* afterwards." (or "... immediately after frobbing is complete.")

In that specific context, the phrase "while frobbing a gronk" makes it clear what "afterwards" is referring to.